# Specify type of collection in subclass

Tags: java

I have an application in which users can play many types of games. Each game extends the `Game` class which has various things relating to the game in it. Each game also has an associated user class which extends `User` (contains email, username etc.) such as `ChessUser` and `ScrabbleUser` which contain statistics and other user information about the game.

In each `Game` class I need a list of all users currently playing the game. As all games will need this list I would like to place it in the `User` class but as it contains the type of user that plays the game (ChessGame would contain a list of ChessUsers) I cannot do this without casting the value when retrieved which I would rather not do. Is there a way of doing this without casting the retrieved value?

Some example code:

```
public class Game {
  private List<Player> players;

  public Player getPlayer(int index) {
    return players.get(index);
  }
}

public class Player {
  private String username;
  private String email;
}

public class ChessGame extends Game {
  // getPlayer now needs to return a ChessPlayer, hopefully without casting
}

public class ChessPlayer extends Player {
  private int checkmates;
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: Check `getPlayer`. Return type is not void, but Player.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use generics:

```
public class Game<T extends Player> {

    private List<T> players;

    public T getPlayer(int index) {
        return players.get(index);
    }
}

public class Player {
  private String username;
  private String email;
}

public class ChessPlayer extends Player {

}

public class Chess extends Game<ChessPlayer> {

}
```

Comment: Are generics good for things such as this? I always thought the point was more for classes who's entire existence is to provide certain kinds of objects.

Comment: Generic type is some kind of refinement for a class. In this case you indicate, that in chess ChessPlayers play.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this functionality using java [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

```
public class Game<T extends Player> {
  private List<T> players;

  public T getPlayer(int index) {
    return players.get(index);
  }
}
```

then specify the correct type in the subclass which will be returned by the `getPlayer` method:

```
public class ChessGame extends Game<ChessPlayer> {
  // getPlayer now needs to return a ChessPlayer, hopefully without casting
}
```